# react native navigate and refresh same screen after delete operation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am using listView. In that List i can delete any record but after deletion i want listview to get refresh and show new record that means i want to call my componentDidMount(). I am using navigation.navigate() but it is not calling componentDidMount(). Below is my code snippet for reference.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Keyboard , TouchableWithoutFeedback ,TextInput, ActivityIndicator, Picker, Switch, ListView,
    Text, View, Alert, Platform, ToastAndroid, TouchableHighlight, Image, Button, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
    import EvilIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
    import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
    import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';

    class manage_timeslots extends Component 
    {
            static navigationOptions = {
            title: 'Manage Timeslots',
        };

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                isLoading: true,
                text: '',
                stat: '',
            }
            this.arrayholder = [];
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            const base64 = require('base-64');
            this._subscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => 
            {    console.log("in focus")
                fetch('APIURL'+this.props.navigation.state.params.campaign_id, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.encode("demo:QZMWOL")
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {  console.log("timeslots: "+ JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        data : "data",
                        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.Time_Slots),
                    }, function () { //console.log("timeslots: " + this.state.dataSource);
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    // Alert.alert(error.toString())
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        data: "noDataFound"
                    })
                });
            });
        }

        onDeleteTimeSlot(Timeslot_id) {
            const base64 = require('base-64');
            fetch('APIURL'+Timeslot_id, {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.encode("demo:QZMWOL")
                }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => { console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                if(responseJson.Message == 'Data has been deleted successfully!')
                { console.log("here");
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Eighth', { campaign_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.campaign_id, ClientId: this.props.navigation.state.params.ClientId, Ad_name: this.props.navigation.state.params.Ad_name }    );
                }
                else 
                {
                    console.log(responseJson);
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

from onDeleteTimeSlot() i need to call componentDidmount() function again to refresh datasource for new records.

Comment: Move the code in componentDidMount to new method and call it from componentDidMount and also after after deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Keyboard , TouchableWithoutFeedback ,TextInput, ActivityIndicator, Picker, Switch, ListView,
Text, View, Alert, Platform, ToastAndroid, TouchableHighlight, Image, Button, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import EvilIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';

class manage_timeslots extends Component 
{
        static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Manage Timeslots',
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            text: '',
            stat: '',
        }
        this.arrayholder = [];
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.getData()
    }

    getData() {
        const base64 = require('base-64');
        this._subscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => 
        {    console.log("in focus")
            fetch('APIURL'+this.props.navigation.state.params.campaign_id, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.encode("demo:QZMWOL")
                }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {  console.log("timeslots: "+ JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data : "data",
                    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.Time_Slots),
                }, function () { //console.log("timeslots: " + this.state.dataSource);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Alert.alert(error.toString())
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: "noDataFound"
                })
            });
        });
    }

    onDeleteTimeSlot(Timeslot_id) {
        const base64 = require('base-64');
        fetch('APIURL'+Timeslot_id, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.encode("demo:QZMWOL")
            }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => { console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
            if(responseJson.Message == 'Data has been deleted successfully!')
            { console.log("here");
                this.getData()
            }
            else 
            {
                console.log(responseJson);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong lifecycle method.`componentDidMount` will only be executed when the component is successfully mounted. When you make changes to the data, the component will be not be unmounted and then remounted for the changes to reflect. You need to use the update lifecycle methods for this purpose or you can even force an update for the component.

By default, when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render. If your `render()` method depends on some other data, you can tell React that the component needs re-rendering by calling `forceUpdate()`

`component.forceUpdate(callback)`

Calling `forceUpdate()` will cause `render()` to be called on the component, skipping `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This will trigger the normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method of each child. React will still only update the DOM if the markup changes.